# TargetProfile gives No default service configuration error

Tags: azure, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-cloud-services

I am building an Azure Cloud service application in a TFS 2012 build definition.  Everything is working properly with the default **Cloud** configuration.  However when I set the `TargetProfile` property in the `MSBuild` arguments I get the following error. The service configuration file exists in the project and I am able to select within the project properties.

Is there something additional I need to do to get the build to recognize the non-default configuration?

#### MSBuild Arguments

> /t:Publish /p:PublishDir=\buildserver\builddrops\LocA\ /p:TargetProfile=CloudLocA

#### Error Message

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (353): No default service configuration "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" could be found in the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out and it ended up not being related to the `TargetProfile` property.  I had my build definition set to only clean the workspace outputs.  When I looked at the sources folder on the build server I realized it wasn't pulling down the additional service configuration files so it couldn't find what I was specifying in the `TargetProfile` property.  I changed the clean workspace setting to all and everything is working now.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried tying the `TargetProfile` to the `$(Configuration)`?  In my last project, I configured the Azure project with the following settings and it worked fine:

```
 ...
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetProfile Condition="'$(TargetProfile)'==''">$(Configuration)</TargetProfile>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <!-- Items for the project -->
 <ItemGroup>
  <ServiceDefinition Include="ServiceDefinition.csdef">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </ServiceDefinition>
  <None Include="ServiceDefinition.Debug.csdef">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <DependentUpon>ServiceDefinition.csdef</DependentUpon>
  </None>
  <None Include="ServiceDefinition.Demo.csdef">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
   <DependentUpon>ServiceDefinition.csdef</DependentUpon>
  </None>
  <None Include="ServiceDefinition.Release.csdef">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <DependentUpon>ServiceDefinition.csdef</DependentUpon>
  </None>
  <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.Debug.cscfg">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </ServiceConfiguration>
  <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.Demo.cscfg">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </ServiceConfiguration>
  <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.Release.cscfg">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </ServiceConfiguration>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would rather not tie the Azure service configuration to the build configuration.  I will try hard coding this in the project file to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to change the service configuration prefix in ccproj of your project, add yourprojectname.configurationname
Dot is the life saver.

```
<ServiceConfigurationPrefix>yourproject.ServiceConfiguration</ServiceConfigurationPrefix>
```

Add these in itemgroup:

```
<ServiceDefinition Include="yourproject.ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
<ServiceConfiguration Include="yourproject.ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" />
```

Make sure you have renamed your cscfg files from the folder it resides.

Reload